# Symfony4 redirects always to index.php

Tags: php, linux, apache, symfony

I am trying to deploy my Symfony 4 app. I started symfony server from directory and it's listening on

> 127:0.0.1:888

My /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nameofdomain.conf is :

```
Listen 888
<VirtualHost *:888>
   ServerName domain.com
   ServerAlias domain.com

   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Project/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/Project/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/Project/public/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain.com_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domain.com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I enter domain:888 I am always redirected to domain:888/index.php/ with error

> No route found for "GET /"

When I enter domain:888/correctPath I have apache error 'Not found'.

I have Apache 2.4.18 and Ubuntu 16.04.
Could you help me how should I serve app?

Comment: You could start by removing `Allow from All` as that is APache 2.2 syntax for `Require all granted`

Comment: You are supposed to be directed to `index.php` thats is the `Front Controller` for Symfony's MVC

Comment: Do you have an application? If not try installing https://github.com/symfony/demo

Answer (score 0):

First

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

Then

```
<VirtualHost *:888>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
    <Directory /var/www/project/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```